# Wordpress WooCommerce: Limit the subcategories list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have list of subcategories or list of products on my side menu. I need to limit it to 5 items and add a button "More..." below. When we click on the button, opens full list.

How can I do it? 
Is there some plugins or hooks for this?

This what I have:

[image]

---

This what I want:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have a problem with your current code? If so please post that code.

Comment: @Christophvh, Each item in my side menu is a "label" and all labels are in "div".
I found this jquery function and I tried to apply it in my case:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7973317/6260651
And I have something like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SRxeVOpIlxQwfGDbBlhw?p=preview

Comment: It could be easy, if you could provide a link to a page of your website.

Comment: It was the answer to my question: stackoverflow.com/a/7973317/6260651     I just a little modificate it